# Run times for while loop (Mathematical)

Tags: algorithm, math, time, complexity-theory, code-analysis

So I need a mathematical expression for the following loop, but I can't seem to grasp it. I am assuming I am just missing something simple.

```
while a <= b
    a = a + a
end
```

Using an analysis, what would be the run time of this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The run time is dependent on the logarithm of `b`. In other words, the time complexity is `O(log N)`.

You can see this if you start `a` at 1 and `b` at 256. Each time through the loop, `a` is doubled so that there are only nine iterations (would be eight if the condition was `< b`).

Each doubling of the `b` value will result in one extra iteration.

Of course, this is complexity analysis, the *runtime* depends on a host of other factors such as (almost certainly not an exhaustive list):

- how fast your machine is.
- what other things it has to do concurrently.
- initial value of `a`: `a == 0` gives infinite run time, `a == b + 1` gives you constant run time.

Comment: I think you mean the logarithm of `b`

Answer (score 1):

Would you agree that each iteration of the loop doubles `a`?  If so, then let `a` have an initial value of 1.  After one iteration, `a == 2`.  After two iterations `a == 4`.  After three, `a == 8`.  After four, `a == 16`; and so on.

Suppose that `b == 64`.  The loop will run seven iterations in this case.  Observe that `log_2(64) == 6`.

Suppose that `b == 128`.  The loop will run eight iterations in this case.  Observe that `log_2(128) == 7`.

Suppose that `b == 256`.  The loop will run nine iterations in this case.  Observe that `log_2(256) == 8`.

Therefore, the run time depends on the logarithm of `b`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're doubling `a` every time, you need `log(b/a)` doublings before the loop will exit.  So the run time is `Theta(log(b/a))`.